# Expecting ArcSDE service in Windows services?

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase

I've been thrown into learning how ArcSDE and ArcGIS Server work.

I'm trying to start a service using the default esri_sde on port 5151.

I put it in both the ArcSDE and windows service files.

When I go to Administrative tools and services, I don't see an ArcSDE service.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using a [direct connect](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002n00000039000000)?

Comment: I'm running ArcGIS Desktop 10.1 Standard and I'm remoted into a computer with Windows Server 2012 which has SQL Server 2012 and ArcSDE installed. I haven't started messing around with Server yet. I am able to create a create a Database connection and access the SDE database.

I'm trying to use the Create ArcSDE Connection file tool, but I'm not able to get it to work. It says that it cannot connect to the server.

Comment: Arcsde is a separate install with 10.1. If you don't see the service it has not been instant imaged with the gdb.  You can find the documentation on the installation machine or ESRI website

Comment: I installed ArcSDE and am able to connect and version my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should see:

The **giomgr** process

This is the ArcSDE service monitor. Each ArcSDE service has one giomgr process. This process listens for user application connection requests, spawns gsrvr processes, and cleans up disconnected user processes. The giomgr will not start if a valid server license has not been installed.
The gsrvr process

The giomgr process spawns a gsrvr process for each application connected to the ArcSDE service. The gsrvr process is dedicated to a single user/application connection. It communicates with the database on behalf of the connected application. The gsrvr process responds to the queries and edit requests the application sends to the database

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002900000045000000

Comment: So if I create 2 databases in SQL Server to house 2 SDE geodatabases, will that start 2 separate giomgr processes or will they share the same one?

Comment: They will be 2 separate processes (but will have the same name in task manager).